# svn newbie: revert the files that I haven't committed

Tags: svn, revert

i have committed just some files of those that i have modified. As you can imagine the rest of the files that i havent committed are showed when i do "svn status".

How can i make "dissapear" those files that are showed when i do "svn status"? Should i revert one by one? A normal revert (svn revert -R .) will revert also the files that i have committed?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Either revert one by one, or `svn revert *` - note that this will revert all changes in current directory.

Comment: a "svn revert *" will also revert the files that i have commited?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a linux box do:

`svn status | grep ^M | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn revert`

Answer (score 1):

Once you commit something, it is no longer "modified" until you modify it again, so there is nothing to "revert".

Comment: so if i do a "svn revert -R ." to revert all the application _only_ will be reverted the files that are showed when i do "svn st" ?

Answer (score 1):

`svn revert -R .` will only revert modified files in the working copy. Any files that you've already committed and that have no more modifications in the current directory will be left 
untouched.

Or, if you prefer, `svn revert -R .` will make your working copy look like the current state of the repository.